# T-SQL Group and sum record set based on value in a given column

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sum

Take the following example:

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE DATE = '2021-09-10'

Date        FirstName  LastName   Adults  Item       Description
----------  ---------  ---------  ------  ---------  --------------
2021-09-10  David      Smith      3       Breakfast  Eggs and beans
2021-09-10  Jennifer   Ford       2       Breakfast  Eggs and beans
2021-09-10  Thomas     Oliver     1       Breakfast  Eggs and beans
2021-09-10  Lisa       Parker     2       Breakfast  Continental
2021-09-10  David      Smith      3       Dinner     Steak
2021-09-10  Tom        Haverford  1       Lunch      Hamburger
2021-09-10  Reanu      Keeves     2       Dinner     Steak
```

.. I need to group and sum so that all the distinct [Breakfast] items combine as one row per; summing the [Adults], while the rest output as separate records:

```
Date        FirstName  LastName   Adults  Item       Description
----------  ---------  ---------  ------  ---------  --------------
2021-09-10                        6       Breakfast  Eggs and beans
2021-09-10                        2       Breakfast  Continental
2021-09-10  David      Smith      3       Dinner     Steak
2021-09-10  Tom        Haverford  1       Lunch      Hamburger
2021-09-10  Reanu      Keeves     2       Dinner     Steak
```

Is there a handy way to build this as a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need `UNION`, you can do this in one query.**

It's just a matter of picking your grouping values carefully:

```sql
SELECT
    [Date],
    FirstName = CASE WHEN Item <> 'Breakfast' THEN FirstName END,
    LastName  = CASE WHEN Item <> 'Breakfast' THEN LastName  END,
    Adults = SUM(Adults),
    Item,
    Description
FROM
    [Orders]
WHERE
    [Date] = '2021-09-10'
GROUP BY
    [Date],
    Item,
    Description,
    CASE WHEN Item <> 'Breakfast' THEN FirstName END,
    CASE WHEN Item <> 'Breakfast' THEN LastName END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6920f1fce6501a9692b7b0a82f265cba)

Answer (score 2):

You can UNION two queries in this way:

```
SELECT
    [Date],
    '' as FirstName,
    '' as LastName,
    SUM(Adults) as Adults,
    Item,
    Description
FROM
    [Orders]
GROUP BY
    [Date],
    Item,
    Description
HAVING
    [Date] = '2021-09-10'
    AND Item = 'Breakfast'

UNION

SELECT
    [Date],
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Adults,
    Item,
    Description
FROM
    [Orders]
WHERE
    [Date] = '2021-09-10'
    AND Item <> 'Breakfast'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4ae808d2d70b8050c9a7bca4badd38f)*